# Pull Request Doesn't update repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, request, put

I am trying to change a Perfil object in PerfilRepository by sending the following request with the following code:

```
   package br.com.bandtec.projetocaputeam.controller;

import br.com.bandtec.projetocaputeam.dominio.*;
import br.com.bandtec.projetocaputeam.service.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/caputeam")
public class CaputeamController {

//USER CLASS

    public abstract class Perfil {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5,max = 30)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z\s]*$", message = "Nome inválido! Digite apenas letras e espaçamento") //Permite apenas letras e espaço
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @CPF
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5,max = 12)
    private String senha;

    private Integer telefone;

    @DecimalMin("0")
    @DecimalMax("5")
    private Double avaliacao;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_endereco")
    private Endereco endereco;

    @NotNull
    private String tipoPerfil;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Categoria categoriaAutonomo;

    //Getters
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public Integer getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public Double getAvaliacao() {
        return avaliacao;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public String getTipoPerfil() {
        return tipoPerfil;
    }

    public Categoria getCategoriaAutonomo() {
        return categoriaAutonomo;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setTipoPerfil(String tipoPerfil) {
        this.tipoPerfil = tipoPerfil;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public void setTelefone(Integer telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public void setAvaliacao(Double avaliacao) {
        this.avaliacao = avaliacao;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public void setCategoriaAutonomo(Categoria categoriaAutonomo) {
        this.categoriaAutonomo = categoriaAutonomo;
    }
}
```

//--- REPOSITORIES

```
   @Autowired
    private PerfilService perfilService = new PerfilService();
//--- USUARIOS
    @GetMapping("/usuarios")
    public ResponseEntity getUsuario(){
        return perfilService.getPerfisRepository();
    }

    @PostMapping("/cadastrar-usuario")
    public ResponseEntity cadastrarUsuario(@RequestBody @Valid Perfil novoPerfil){
        return perfilService.cadastrarUsuario(novoPerfil);
    }

    @PutMapping("/usuarios/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity alterarUsuario(@RequestBody @Valid Perfil usuarioAlterado, @PathVariable int id){
        return perfilService.alterarPerfil(usuarioAlterado,id);
    }
```

And thats my method for changing my perfil object

```
    public ResponseEntity alterarPerfil(Perfil perfilAlterado, int id){

    perfisRepository.findById(id).map(perfil -> {
        perfil.setNome(perfilAlterado.getNome());
        perfil.setEmail(perfilAlterado.getEmail());
        perfil.setTelefone(perfilAlterado.getTelefone());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
});
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Alteração inválida!");
```

}

Im sending my put request in postman like that:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Beatriz Barros",
    "cpf": "103.725.810-05",
    "email": "bia@hotmail.com",
    "senha": "121520",
    "telefone": 1134577777,
    "avaliacao": 4.9,
    "endereco": {
        "id": 1,
        "cep": "03311111",
        "bairro": "Vila Poeira",
        "logradouro": "RuaFlor",
        "numeroLogradouro": 7,
        "complemento": null,
        "uf": "sp",
        "cidade": "SaoPaulo"
    },
    "tipoPerfil": "autonomo",
    "categoriaAutonomo": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Jardineiro",
        "descricao": null
    },
    "precoAutonomo": 0.0
}
```

But it always returns status 400 bad request!
I already tried to send only the fields I want to change (name, email and phone) but it also didn't work

I also tried to send with and without the ID and nothing to work

How can I send a correct request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's actually what you're doing.

```
    perfisRepository.findById(id).map(perfil -> {
        perfil.setNome(perfilAlterado.getNome());
        perfil.setEmail(perfilAlterado.getEmail());
        perfil.setTelefone(perfilAlterado.getTelefone());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
});
```

`perfil -> { /* */ }` is actually a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) or in other words: an anonymous method. So instead of returning in the `alterarPerfil` method, you're returning in the anonymous method.

I've never worked with Spring, but from reading the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html), I assume that `perfisRepository` is implementing the `CrudRepository` interface.

The right code should be something like:

```
Perfil oldObject = perfisRepository.findById(id).get();

if(oldObject == null) return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Alteração inválida!");

oldObject.setNome(perfilAlterado.getNome());
oldObject.setEmail(perfilAlterado.getEmail());
/* and so on - you probably want to use reflection or a helping class to save you some time here */
// For a given entity, save will act as update too.
perfisRepository.save(oldObject);
return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
```

Since in your code, you aren't persisting any change.

Comment: that was exactly my problem! Thank you very much, I think I ended up creating a fixed thought and didn't even notice the slip!